# making a shape fall down in different layers in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

New to programing... I want to make objects fall straight down in flash at different speeds. Kind of like an ascii art raining down from the top to the make the shape at the bottom of the artboard. There are 600 pieces. So there must be a better way to automate this. The problem is that the artwork is in layers in illustrator. So I want to apply a script to randomly make each layer fall 375 pixels. The script i use is for creating a shape and moving.  Not importing shapes already made ... Help!

And do i put the action script in each symbol?

Thanks in advance.
derob357

```
function moveDown(e:Event):void {      e.target.y += speed; /* e.target refers to circle_mc. We    are incrementing the y property to make it move down */       /* This will stop the animation when the movie clip reaches a certain point */      if(e.target.y >= 350)      {           circle_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);      } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your variable speed, you can easily make it a random speed by the following `Math.random()` function:

```
var high:int = 10;
var low:int = 1;
var speed:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+high-low))+low;
```

This will generate a random number between 1 and 10, change the variables high and low in order to change the limits.

Comment: Do i put the function on each symbol? When I do break apart they stop moving in the tween.

Comment: @Deric Robinson Create a class and put it on the movieclip and use an array loop to create a bunch and add function to each item in array.